# Travelling Business class from Edinburgh to Heathrow

Tags: business-travel, lounges

Travelling Business class from Edinburgh to Heathrow, will I be able to access the business lounge while waiting for my flights on another airline? (same day)

Comment: another way to phrase this would be "is there an arrivals lounge at Heathrow, and will it be practical for me to use it?" - however without knowing what airline you're arriving on, the first half can't be answered, and without knowing what airline you're leaving on and how long you have to transfer, the second half can't be answered. Please edit.

Comment: I doubt there's a UK arrivals lounge that permits entry following a domestic flight. Lounge access will be decided based on the incoming airline, outgoing airline, class of service of each, whether they're one ticket or two and whether they're in the same alliance.